# Junit: Mocking object which are not pass as an argument to object

Tags: junit

How can we use the object of a class inside a method which are not passes as an argument to the method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to *inject* this object rather than just rely on it being instantiated by the class itself.

See [this article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) on dependency injection, and [this article](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200709/dependency-injection-unit-testing.html) for info specific to testing.

Comment: Might also need to use a factory which can also be mocked to return a mock.